# google_visualr chart rendering error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, google-visualization

i am trying Google-Visualr gem and got the above error.

As described [here](https://github.com/winston/google_visualr).

i installed the gem and in `MyModel` (we can use controller/model) i copied the demo code for line-chart from [here](http://googlevisualr.herokuapp.com/examples/interactive/line_chart).

i have a `UserMailer`,where i wanted to render html page along with my chart and using pdfkit i am converting rendered html to pdf.

```
    class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
        def my_report
            @chart =MyModel.line_chart
             html_data = render :template => "user_mailer/my_report"
             kit = PDFKit.new(html_data,:page_size => 'Letter')
             pdf = kit.to_pdf
        end
```

in my `my_report` view i included

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
```

in `<head>`

included this in `<body>` part

```
<div id='chart'></div>
<%= render_chart(@chart, 'chart') %>
```

But it is leading to me to `undefined method "render_chart"` error.

Any suggestion that how can i render chart with my html data?
where i am going wrong?

i am using `rails 4`
and `'google_visualr', '>= 2.1'`

Comment: Im new to rails myself but if I should guess, you should replace `render_chart` with `render chart`. Remove the underscore?

Comment: i am following https://github.com/winston/google_visualr.


i tried like this <%= @chart.render('chart')%>

Comment: I got the example graph. Can you get the example graph by any chance?

Comment: In `views > layouts > application.html.erb` you should have the script: `<script src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>`. Do you?

Comment: when i do the same example in controller with associated view i also got the graph. But i am trying to access the chart from MODEL. Then it is giving me the above error.

Comment: Sorry. Cant help you with this as everywhere I look, everyone has it in the controller, not model.

Just create a `ChartsController` for it your charts.